# Django form not working once I change URL's

Tags: python, django

Very new to Django, but have followed a tutorial to create a SQLite3 DB which is added to and updated from forms on various html pages.
Once I try to change the URL's involved from `path('',include('members.urls')),` to `path('members/',include('members.urls')),` issues arise. The submit button for changing the entries for the database keeps POST'ing to "127.0.0.1:8000/update/1" instead of "127.0.0.1:8000/members/update/1"

Here is what I think might be relevant code in case someone can help out?

Project urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('members/',include('members.urls')),
path('',include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))
]
```

Members views.py

```
def update(request,id):
if request.method=='POST':
    time=request.POST['time']
    player1=request.POST['player1']
    player2=request.POST['player2']
    player3=request.POST['player3']
    Post.objects.filter(id=id).update(time=time,player1=player1,player2=player2,player3=player3)
    messages.success(request,'Data has been updated')
post=Post.objects.get(id=id)
return render(request,'update.html',{'post':post})
```

Members urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('teetimes/',views.teetimes,name='teetimes'),
path('add/',views.add,name='add'),
path('update/<int:id>',views.update,name='update')
]
```

Members teetimes.html

```
 <h3>All Times</h3>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <th><h5>{{post.time}} <br> <a href="/update/{{post.id}}"  class="btn-sm btn-success">Update</a></h5></th>
                    <th><h6>{{post.player1}}</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>{{post.player2}}</h6></th>
                    <th><h6>{{post.player3}}</h6></th>
                </table>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Members update.html

```
% if messages %}
                {% for msg in messages %}
                    <p class="text-success">{{msg}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <form method="post" action="/update/{{post.id}}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value="{{post.time}}" type="text" name="time" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Player 1</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value="{{post.player1}}" type="text" name="player1" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Player 2</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value="{{post.player2}}" type="text" name="player2" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Player 3</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value="{{post.player3}}" type="text" name="player3" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using URL like this `update/{{post.id}}` use like this `{% url 'update' post.id %}` in form action.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried swapping this in teetimes.html and update.html, but all I get is an error of "did you forget to register or load this tag".

Comment: Hello @dos29 sorry it was silly mistake check i've changed `URL` to `url`